# Is there a way to thin the MobileSync folder?

Tags: iphone, backup

I would like to reduce the size of the folder `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync`. I don't want to delete it, remove any files directly, or symlink it to another drive. Is that possible?

A lot of the files backed up here are photos and/or videos I have imported elsewhere. At what point are files removed from my iPhone also removed from the backups?

Comment: Why do you want to "thin" this?  The files in this folder is what's synced to iCloud.  Delete these and you delete them from iCloud as well.

Comment: @Allan ~/Library/MobileDocuments is iCloud Drive, ~/Library/App Supp/MobileSync/ hosts the Backups/ folder, which holds iOS device backups.

Comment: @Allan I should have clarified. These are local backups only. I do not back up anything to iCloud. The reason I want to reduce the size is that it has grown to 50+ gigabytes due in large part to having backed up photos and videos. But now that these are in Photos there is no need to keep them in the backup.